# Integrating wix + paypal takes to paypal signup/login page on checkout

Tags: paypal, velo

I am trying to integrate my wix website with paypal.But when somebody tries to checkout paypal its getting redirected to paypal login/signup page. I want to allow checkout even for people without paypal credentials.But unable to find the right solution.

Please Note: PayPal account optional setting is also set to ON, still its redirecting to paypal sign up/login page

Answer (score 0):

This is normal PayPal behavior, whether the sign up is required will depend in part on their country and your country.  If it's required, it's required. This is the standard PayPal checkout.

An alternative integration you can consider is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , which has a black Debit/Credit Card button that expands.  However, WIX may not have built-in support for this newer PayPal checkout button.

Comment: Wix does not have built in support for those buttons. Is dr any way of adding those buttons manually in checkout page ?

Comment: Not in a way that will integrate with Wix's cart functionality, no